# With a pawn rush, should I take the knight?

Tags: opening, analysis, captures

I was just playing the computer, and it always starts with the knight on b1, moves out his other knight, and then plays his pawn. At this point, should I take his knight with my pawn, or do something else?

```
[fen "rnbqkbnr/ppp1pppp/8/8/3pP3/2N2N2/PPPP1PPP/R1BQKB1R b KQkq - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Definitely take the knight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the c3 knight. Since white has developed only one piece, he can't punish you.  If he takes back with the d pawn, trade queens. Now he can't castle.  Then you develop, move your rooks to the center, and push him off the back of the board.

Comment: Also note that trading queens makes the material advantage more noticeable

Answer (score 0):

Always take the material unless there is a very clear reason not to.
White has nothing that is worth the horsie that he can do to you.

next play bn5 and pk3 and then develop your other pieces.  of course if white takes your pawn with the qp then trade queens first.